# Import and Export javascript

Tags: javascript

I am writing some Javascript code. I created a js file which contain my exports. However, when I import it into the other js file, I get an error which says `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.`

I am using WebStorm. Here is the code:

```
exports(math.js).

export var add=function (n1,n2) { return n1 + n2; };

export var subtract=function (n1,n2) { return n1 - n2; };

export var multiply=function (n1,n2) { return n1 * n2; };

export var divide=function (n1,n2) { return n1 / n2; };


import import * as math from './math';

console.log(math.add(2,2)); console.log(math.subtract(2,2)); console.log(math.multiply(2,2)); console.log(math.divide(2,2));
```

Comment: Have you tried copy/pasting the error message into Google?

Comment: yes I did but could not find a satisfying answer.

Comment: Add the code you wrote to the post

Comment: @MajedBadawi — What would that tell us that the error message doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

use require instead of import

```js
const someImported =require('fileName.js')
```

Comment: That would only work if the environment supports `require`

Comment: Sorry required did not work.

Comment: can you share the code in order to know the context